# Angular: ActivatedRoute's snapshot has no data

Tags: angular

I have the following URL: `http://localhost:4200/?token=test`. My objective is to log `test` inside the `AppComponent`.
I decided to use `ActivatedRoute`'s snapshot to fetch the token:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.token);
}
```

But it prints `undefined`. I decided to print the `activatedRoute` itself and the snapshot:

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute);
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot);
```

That's what I have:
[image: Console]
Such a strange behavior, right? Thus I cannot fetch the token. How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Is your AppComponent routable? How does your route definition look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that when the app component initialize the route hasn't been initialized yet

so you can use setTimeOut to tell it to wait a tick but it it's not 100% will work always

or you can subscribe to the query params and get the params whenever they change, but notice that you will get the empty object at first time, you can use filter to prevent empty object from invoking your subscribe function, or just have if condition in your subscribe, it's up to you

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // wait a tick
      console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);
    });
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      // get params whenever they change, it will print twice the first with empty object, the second with the correct token
      console.log(params.token);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is not specific to app.component.ts. Your objective was to log token and filter removes undefined values, that's why filter is used in above answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably the **AppComponent** is not the right place. You should try to get `ActivatedRoute` **snapshot** from the route associated with a component loaded in an outlet at a particular moment in time. Usually in AppComponent is placed `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where we load all other routes (components), like Home, About and etc.

Comment: Usually a component is to late to subscribe to ActivateRoute (it fires pretty early) so ppl use services and put them into the first component...

Answer (score 0):

Url:-  http://localhost:4200/?token=test

## app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
 console.log("OnInit");
 const self  = this;
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(filter(params => params['token']))
    .subscribe(params => {     
        self.token = params['token']; 
        console.log(params['token']); //<====== log here
       });
    }

 ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
    const self  = this;
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(filter(params => params['token']))
       .subscribe(params => {     
            self.token = params['token']; 
            console.log( params['token']);  //<====== log here
         });
      }
 }
```

Comment: why the self const?